# Is it possible to take a screenshot from a dialog in Mass Effect 2?

Tags: mass-effect-2

I managed to bind a key to making a screenshot in Mass Effect 2. It works if I'm playing the game but as soon as I start a dialog with someone it is not working. Do you have any idea what could be the problem? Any workarounds?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some research it turned out that the game itself does not let you do this but **Fraps** proved to be an excellent tool to do so without the hassle.

Answer (score 11):

Launching Mass Effect 2 via Steam (whether owned on Origin and added to your Steam library as a non-Steam game, or owned on Steam) will allow you to use <kbd>F12</kbd> to take a screenshot via Steam on any screen in the game.

You could also use a program like [FRAPS](http://www.fraps.com/) or [GameCam](http://v2.planetgamecam.com/) to capture the screen.

Finally, it is possible to use <kbd>Print Screen</kbd> to take screenshots in Mass Effect 2 by running the game in bordered window mode. This will require the additional step of pasting it into an image editor like MSPaint though.

There are actually [a couple of console commands available](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/PC_Tweaks#Commands) if you unlock and bind access to the console, but these do not appear to work:

```
shot         take a screenshot
tiledshot    takes a high resolution screenshot
```

It looks like these commands are supposed to save a screenshot to `%My Documents%\BioWare\Mass Effect 2\ScreenShots` however nothing seems to happen when using them. (Tested with the Steam release of the game)